# Best way to manipulate and cut a string using character matching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, substring

So in my example, we have strings that look like this:
`CP1_ctl05_RCBPAThursdayStartTimePicker_0_dateInput`
`CP1_ctl05_RCBPAFridayStartTimePicker_3_dateInput`
`CP1_ctl05_RCBPAMondayStartTimePicker_1_dateInput`

The task is to extract the days of the week from the string.

I already figured you can trim the first set of characters `CP1_ctl05_RCBPA` as they will always have the same length and will always occur in the same position. Using `string.substr(15)`, I was able to reduce the string to `FridayStartTimePicker_3_dateInput` but I am not sure how to approach deleting the rest of the suffixal garbage text.

I was thinking about trimming the end by finding the first occurring y (as it will only occur in days of the week in this case) and slicing off the end up until that point, but I am not sure about how to approach slicing off a part of a string like this.

Comment: use *regex* .­­

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to extract them. As every day ends with a `y`, and no day has a y in between, you can simply use that as delimiter

```js
const regex = /\w{15}(\w+y).*/g;
const str = `CP1_ctl05_RCBPAThursdayStartTimePicker_0_dateInput`;
const subst = `\$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Much more elegant (and possibly better performance wise) than trimming and snipping the string!

Comment: I think it is, yeah. @Bitz Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting unwanted parts, you could just match what you want.

The following regex `^.{15}(\w+?y)` matches 15 any character from the begining of the string then matches and capture in group 1 one or more word character not greedy then the letter `y`. It is mandatory to use not greedy `?` unless it will match until the **last** `y` that exists in the string.

We then just have to get the content of the first group and assign to variable `day`

```js
var test = [
'CP1_ctl05_RCBPAThursdayStartTimePicker_0_dateInput', 'CP1_ctl05_RCBPAFridayStartTimePicker_3_dateInput', 'CP1_ctl05_RCBPAMondayStartTimePicker_1_dateInput'
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a.match(/^.{15}(\w+?y)/)[1]
}));
```